# Code only works with the jQuery version 1.4.2

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, version

I got this code for pagination

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='img/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
```

But apparently only works with this version of jQuery, because when I change it doesn't works

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I need to use this version

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I need to change for make it work.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: what is exactly didn't work?  ajax or click event or ... ?  .. try to change .live()  with .on()

Comment: There are any number of plugins available for jQuery. Rather than wasting time on this, why not search for a newer one?

Answer (score 1):

[From the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

So where you have `.live` change to `.on`. That's your first port of call. There may be other deprecations, although I can't see any others I know off hand.

Bring up your web browsers JavaScript console to see JavaScript errors. For this you should have seen something along the lines of `live() is undefined or not a function`. That would have helped you work out what the issue was, and will help for future JS debugging.

Comment: Almost works i change it but it only shows the loading gift but not the table, but when i change     
$("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });     with this   $("#container").html(msg);   displays the table but the click it doesn't work